# Scale not updating during key inputs

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, slider

I am currently working on scales using tkinter. I have gotten the code to work except one thing. I have bound keys to the motion of a servo motor. When I press the keys however the scale does not follow what the key bindings do.How can I get the scale to follow the key bindings?

Please see code below

....GPIO setup code above not shown...

```
def fMin(event):
    iDCServo = 2.5
    pServo.ChangeDutyCycle(iDCServo) #this is pwm code for the servo motor
def fMin2(event):
    iDCServo = 7.5
    pServo.ChangeDutyCycle(iDCServo)
def fMax(event):
    iDCServo = 12.5
    pServo.ChangeDutyCycle(iDCServo)
def fMax2(event):
    iDCServo = 7.5
    pServo.ChangeDutyCycle(iDCServo)
def fOperation():

    global guiSliderServo1, iLoop
    while True:
        win = Tk()
        win.wm_title(">>>Servo Slider<<<")
        win.geometry("800x100+0+0")

        guiSliderServo1 = Scale(win, from_=-45, to_=45, orient=HORIZONTAL, length_=700, sliderlength_=10, tickinterval_=5, command=fSliderServo1)
        guiSliderServo1.set(0)
        guiSliderServo1.grid(row=0)
        guiSliderServo1.pack(side=TOP)

        guiSliderServo1.bind('<Key-q>', fMin)
        guiSliderServo1.bind('<KeyRelease-q>', fMin2)
        guiSliderServo1.bind('<Key-e>', fMax)
        guiSliderServo1.bind('<KeyRelease-e>', fMax2)

        guiSliderServo1.focus_set()


        guiButtonExit = Button(win, text="Exit Slider", command=quit)
        guiButtonExit.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        win.mainloop()
```

...there is some remaining code regarding looks, functions and imports not shown, not sure, but probably would just clutter the real question.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The while True hogs the computer so there is no time left for Tkinter to update the widget.  You should be able to just delete the while True in  the above code and be fine because Tkinter's mainloop() essentially does the same thing, i.e. continually checks for a keypress.  Also mixing grid and pack, you use both, yields unknown results.  Settle on one and use it.  Note that this code does not change the scale, and the Button command should be win.quit.

Comment: mixing grid and pack, in this specific case, won't yield unknown results. the effects of grid are nullified as soon as pack is called on the same widget.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick replies. I have taken the while statement out and the issue was not solved. Regarding the grid and pack...noted thanks. The slider still remains centered and does not move? Would it help to change the state of the slider?

Comment: The set function sets the value.  You have to call this function when you want it to move..